# How can I provide a RGBA png file to OpenAI PHP library

Tags: php, rgba, openai-api

I import [Orhanerday\OpenAi](https://github.com/orhanerday/open-ai) library to my DALL-E Examples project but when I provide images, I got `Invalid input image - format must be in ['RGBA'], got RGB.` error. I search for this error on the internet but I got nothing.

My code looks like

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // remove this line if you use a PHP Framework.

use Orhanerday\OpenAi\OpenAi;

$open_ai_key = getenv("OPENAIKEY");
$open_ai = new OpenAi($open_ai_key);
 
$otter = curl_file_create("C:\Users\dotor\OneDrive\Desktop\dalle-examples\otter.png");
$mask = curl_file_create("C:\Users\dotor\OneDrive\Desktop\dalle-examples\mask.png");

$result = $open_ai->imageEdit([
    "image" => $otter,
    "mask" => $mask,
    "prompt" => "A cute baby sea otter wearing a beret",
    "n" => 2,
    "size" => "256x256",
]);

var_dump($result);
```

Png files;

*otter.png;*
[image: otter.png]
*mask.png;*
[image: mask.png]

I need to get a result without any errors, what is an RGBA png file and how can I provide?

Comment: Your image doesn't have an alpha channel, you can use an image editor (Photoshop, GIMP etc.) to add one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The A in RGBA stands for Alpha, which is simply a value for opacity. Since this is the type needed for OpenAI, you should convert the plain RGB to RGBA leveraging an existing library. In python, I used the Python Image Library (PIL) convert function to complete this task.